# How can I fix my routerLink in my Angular Project

Tags: angular, routerlink

Hello guys I'm learning Angular and we created a HeroesApp but my routerLink doesn't work, I imported and exported my routerModule and I don't know how can I fix it.
[`auth-routing.module.ts`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU1A6.png)
[`auth-routing.module.ts part2`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhxZN.png) 
[`folders`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z26r4.png)

for the moment I tried this other route thinking I had a problem with the route I posted (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYQDb.png)

Comment: why do you want to use child routes, use like this https://angular.io/guide/router#defining-a-basic-route

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '/auth/login', component: LoginComponent }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your routerLink is fine. But in auth-routing.module.ts is not setup correctly.

There are two types of routing

1. Normal routing
2. With Lazy loading

Normal routing should be like as below:

```
   const routes: Routes = [
     {
       path: 'login', component:LoginComponent
     }
   ]
```

Lazy loading routing should be like as below:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'customers',
      loadChildren: () =>
      import('./customers/customers.module').then((m) => m.CustomersModule),
    }
  ]
```

for more details I have created a demo for angular route. it will be helpful for you. [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8v13wh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)